# LightBox2 producing error

Tags: wordpress, lightbox2

Site: http://www.onlinetestspace.com/project45/before-after

I have followed lightBox instructions http://leandrovieira.com/projects/jquery/lightbox/ and chrome is giving me the error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Object # has no method 'lightBox'.

Can somebody please help me out?

Answer (score 1):

I just investigate the things and i guess you are using old version of JQuery file (jQuery 1.2.3). Use the latest version of [JQuery](https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js) file and this will fix your problem.

Comment: A quick check of the `<head>` shows one inclusion of jQuery from the WordPress theme directory and one getting linked from the Google library. In my opinion, the theme is the one at fault. A WP theme shouldn't package jQuery with it, it should use the standard `wp_enqueue_script('jquery')` method, and you should install a plugin that will link in the Google libraries rather than using the jQuery version included with the WP install (which maybe you have already done).

Comment: I built the theme, lol... Its a freelance project. I was just having a 'funny five minutes' :P

Answer (score 0):

The reason I was getting this error, was simply because of 2 conflicting files.